# Android - WebView findall not functioning correctly on 4.0.3 and 4.0

Tags: java, android, search, webview

This little bit of code is so frustrating.  I know that it is depreciated in 4.1 but it does function, and for 2.3.3 it works just fine.

```
wv.findAll(findBox.getText().toString());

    try {
      Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
      m.invoke(wv, true);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {

    }
```

I really hope that someone knows of a workaround for this to highlight searched text in my webview for Android 4.0.3 and 4.0.I also know that it does still function correctly as a search which is good, but it just does not highlight in 4.0.3 and 4.0.